# How to change the value of the input field using React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React. I'm going through this link "https://www.telerik.com/blogs/up-and-running-with-react-form-validation". My objective is how to change the error while entering the data

Comment: please provide some codes

Comment: why not use formik or react-hook-forms? and not worry about reinventing the wheel? also please provide code.

Comment: @sanjana Please check the length of error after response came from server. if it is empty remove error. Please give some code. It will be good to explain

Comment: @Niyongabo - Hi, I've updated the code, Could you please check it once

Comment: @PrashanthReddyBalemula - Hi, I've updated the code, Could you please check it once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are receiving the error message literally from your API, I am assuming you are saving it somewhere in your state. All you have to do is remove that error message from your state as soon as your user starts typing in the field. Edit your input field like this:

`<input onChange={() => this.setState({ ...this.state, errorMessage: '' })} />`

By this way, as your user starts typing, the error message resets to an empty string (please replace `errorMessage` with the name you hold your error message in.)

Comment: I have updated the code. Could you please assist me by seeing the code

Comment: Could you please assist me by seeing the above code?

Comment: Sorry I saw this late. Do you still need help with it?

Comment: It got solved but having another issue... how to show suggestion like "Name should have letters" while typing the name in the input field?

Comment: If you want to conditionally render that, check out Formik and Yup as a form validation. Or if it's just one input field, you can manually check what's the input in `onChange` event listener and do a regex check, which would update your `nameHaveLetters` state piece which would start originally false but when regex returns true then you change it to true too. That's how I would do that.